# extract multiple arguments of a xml tag line by line using sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE nmaprun>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/bin/../share/nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<taskprogress task="Service scan" time="1547503455" percent="88.24" remaining="2" etc="1547503456"/>
<host starttime="1547503444" endtime="1547503476"><status state="up" reason="arp-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="0.0.0.0" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="08:00:27:7F:02:62" addrtype="mac" vendor="Oracle"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<ports><port protocol="tcp"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack"/><service product="prod1" version="3.0.2" ostype="Unix" method="probed" conf="10"><cpe>cpe:/a:vsftpd:vsftpd:3.0.2</cpe></service><script id="banner" output="220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="64"/><service product="secure" version="6.6.1p1 Ubuntu 2ubuntu2" extrainfo="Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0" ostype="Linux" method="probed" conf="10"><cpe>cpe:/a:openbsd:openssh:6.6.1p1</cpe><cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel</cpe></service><script id="banner" output="SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="64"/><service product="hello i am here" hostname=" typhoon" method="probed" conf="10"><cpe>cpe:/a:postfix:postfix</cpe></service><script id="banner" output="220 typhoon ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="64"/><service product="who am i" version="9.9.5-3" extrainfo="Ubuntu Linux" ostype="Linux" method="probed" conf="10"><cpe>cpe:/a:isc:bind:9.9.5-3</cpe><cpe>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel</cpe></service></port>
</ports>
```

I want to search for string 'state="open"' and then print the value of product and version tags present in that line ( if version not present - just print product value alone)

I used the following sed command:

```
cat sample.xml | grep 'state="open"' | egrep -o 'product=".*"' | sed -nE 's/^.*product="([^"]*)".*version="([^"]*)".*$/\1, \2/;p' > output.txt
```

The output I get:

```
prod1, 3.0.2
secure, 6.6.1p1 Ubuntu 2ubuntu2
<port protocol="tcp"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="64"/><service product="hello i am here" hostname=" typhoon" method="probed" conf="10"><cpe>cpe:/a:postfix:postfix</cpe></service><script id="banner" output="220 typhoon ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)"/></port>
who am i, 9.9.5-3
```

the output I want:

```
prod1, 3.0.2
secure, 6.6.1p1 Ubuntu 2ubuntu2
hello i am here
who am i, 9.9.5-3
```

Note - If version tag not present, its printing the entire line. I really appreciate if anyone can help me in this. Thanks!

Comment: FYI - the egrep part of the command is unnecessary - even if we remove it, output will remain intact.

Comment: Show valid XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one `awk` command will do:

```
$ awk '/state="open"/{match($0, /product="([^"]*)"/, p); match($0, /version="([^"]*)"/,v); if (p[1]) {printf p[1]; if (v[1]) printf ", " v[1];} print "";}' sample.xml
prod1, 3.0.2
secure, 6.6.1p1 Ubuntu 2ubuntu2
hello i am here
who am i, 9.9.5-3
```

Note, judge and copy from your string of commands' behavior, when there's no `product`, will have no print even if `version` presented. -- You can adjust this if you want.